# Как в js вывести на страницу браузера изображение закодированное в base64?

Tags: javascript, html, base64

Из БД достается массив в котором находится закодированное в `base64` изображение, как вывести его на экран браузера, чтобы при этом можно было работать с ним в `CSS`?

Answer (score 1):

Поместите полученную строку как [`Data URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) в источник изображения:

```
//base64DataString - строка с кодом
let image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64DataString;
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с проверкой (ваша аватарка):

```js
const base64 = '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';
const img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
img.src = `data:image/png;base64,${base64}`;
```

```css
img {outline: 3px solid blue !important;}
```